# How do I get values that are not there in multiple different keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get the entries that are not there with different `b`
say, in the below example

Case 1:
Here I want only `{a: '2', b: '9'}` and not the other 2 entries

```
let array = [{a: '1', b: '9'}, {a: '1', b: '8'}, {a: '2', b: '9'}]
```

Case 2:
Here I want all the entries but removing the duplicates.

```
let array = [{a: '1', b: '9'}, {a: '1', b: '9'}, {a: '2', b: '9'}]
```

Any help will be grateful. Thank you

Comment: what is the result of case 2? what have you tried?

Comment: Case 2 should get all the entries. I want both the cases in a single function. Tries using filter and indexOf but couldn't get a perfect solution.

Comment: Array.prototype.filter() may be your friend.

Comment: why do you want only the last one with `b: '9'` instead of the first and for case 2 all?

Comment: @NinaScholz As case 1, a with same id consists in 2 different b so I don't want that. And In case 2, a with same id consists in same b so I want that

Comment: what is *id* ...?